# Core-Data migration half-not-working

Tags: ios, core-data, installation, core-data-migration

I have an app already running fine, with a data model.
I am currently working on a new version of this app, with a new data model.

Here is what happens:

1. when I install the new version on top of the old app (with RW access
   DB), the installation works fine.
2. when I try install the new version
           without the old version on the device (or the old app with RO access
           DB), then it does not work.

I would like the installation to work in all cases. But I am not sure what is wrong.

Here is the error message I get when trying to install the app on a device without the old version installed:

```
2014-11-26 19:03:40.152 TheApp[9256:60b] (persistentStoreCoordinator):Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134100 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 134100.)" UserInfo=0x17e8b3a0 {metadata={
    NSPersistenceFrameworkVersion = 479;
    NSStoreModelVersionHashes =     {
        InitialList = <b67469ea dcde5008 887e8f41 417d8560 3e36a123 2d737e84 a64bade4 a8f5761b>;
    };
    NSStoreModelVersionHashesVersion = 3;
    NSStoreModelVersionIdentifiers =     (
        ""
    );
    NSStoreType = SQLite;
    NSStoreUUID = "04AB772F-ED6B-46BA-2929-481513806FA6”;
    "_NSAutoVacuumLevel" = 2;
}, reason=The model used to open the store is incompatible with the one used to create the store}
2014-11-26 19:03:40.155 TheApp[9256:60b] Unresolved error (null), (null)
```

The message says “reason=The model used to open the store is incompatible with the one used to create the store”
but this does not happen when an old version of the app (with RW access DB) is installed.

Comment: What are you trying to do by switching between read-only and read-write modes?

Comment: I am not doing anything by switching between RO and RW modes. The app is using a RO DB when installed, and may stay RO for ever.
If the user goes beyond certain limits when using the app, it may also go into RW mode.
There is no point to explain here why the need to change mode is necessary. But this works (very well) as expected anyway.
The problem I am talking about comes when I want to install a new version of the app with a slightly different data-model for Core-Data.
The first(old) model has one entity, the new model has the same entity plus a few more entities.

Comment: I asked because your question says that the problem depends on which one you're using, so understanding why you'd use one or the other is directly relevant to the problem at hand. If you don't want to explain, fine, but there's every sign that your problem depends on the switch.

Comment: I can explain if that helps. While developing I am using read-write access, because I need to build the contents.
Once this is done and the app is ready to ship, there is no reason to keep read-write access.
That is when I want to use the .sqlite file that I copied into the bundle as I always do. Doing that I avoid taking useless space in the Documents Directory.
That means I want the production version of the app to use readonly mode. This is what I cannot do.